# Resolving bindings with a controller class

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I've a component with a controller class, which use a bindings object as an input parameter. I can access to the param in the controller after the constructor runs. But I cannot pass it as a constructor parameter.

Making a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/g93t0QM0NXJWhacn90rS?p=info) I found a posible solution using the $onInit method. [(ui-router doc)](https://ui-router.github.io/guide/ng1/route-to-component).

But this is the correct way?. Hope this helps to someone, and please tell me if it can be improved.

This is the controller:

```js
class Controller {
  constructor(){
    'ngInject';
    this.$onInit = function(){      // Comment this
       this.problemScopeHere = angular.copy(this.param);  
    }                               // Comment this
    console.log(this.param);            
  }
  get(){
    this.problemScopeHere = this.param;
  }
}
```

And here the component

```js
 let Component = {
   bindings : {
      param : "="
   },
   controller : Controller,
   controllerAs: '$ctrl',
   templateUrl: 'component.html'
};

let app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router']);
app.component('comp', Component);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use `resolve`, cause with your version on UI Router you can use [routing to component](https://ui-router.github.io/guide/ng1/route-to-component):

```
.state('app.home' ,{
      url: '/home',
      component: 'comp',
      bindigns: {
        param: 'param',
      },
      resolve: {
        param: function () {
          return {
            string: 'I am the object param'
          }
        }
      }
    });
```

Working fiddle (a little bit different from yours, cause I don't know `home.html` is really needed, I think it's only for demonstration purposes): https://plnkr.co/edit/jaXQN7YmmkI8AC1DxohI?p=preview. And also, you can't use bindings before first `$onChanges` (first run is just before `$onInit`), or `$onInit` runs, from Angular 1.6, so it's recommended to do not rely on them in `contructor` - you can rely on them in `$onInit`, and I think resolve is most modern way to do it - I used to do passing parameters like you, inside `template`, but from UI Router 1.x it's easier. You can declare `$onInit` as regular class method. And also, you don't have to use `controllerAs: $ctrl`. `$ctrl`is used as default value if you don't provide one - and I encourage you to always use a default value, for consistency across all your components.

Answer (score 0):

You should just add param as a property to your controller class.